# codelite projects is not building in ubuntu-14.04 LTS

Tags: gcc, makefile, codelite

I am using editor codelite-9.1.0 version. I have 20 project attached with a workspace.All project were building properly before earsing the OS from my machine. I am using ubuntu-14.04 LTS os. Now some of the project were building properly and some project are not building. I am getting below error while building the project 
`/bin/sh -c ' -j 4 -e -f  Makefile'`
`/bin/sh: 1: -j: not found`
Could you please help me why this error is coming for some project?

Comment: Please take a look at Settings->Build settings... from the menu. How many different build tools do you have configured? Try to work out which build tool is being used for the projects that are working and those which are failing. Look at the line "Make", should be something like "/usr/bin/make -j4" without quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The build line indicates that CodeLite could not configure a proper compiler toolchain.

You should let CodeLite scan for the installed compilers, follow [these instructions](http://codelite.org/AddNewCompiler/AddNewCompiler#toc4) to auto scan and configure the compilers in CodeLite

If no compilers were found, please install one: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Next, try to build your project and CodeLite will do one of the following:

- Build your project without a problems
- If the compiler assigned to the project no longer exists, CodeLite will allow you to fix this by assigning new compiler

HTH
Eran